# Подключение Skype4COM.dll к проекту

Tags: c++, dll, skype

Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку Skype4COM.dll для написания бота. Использовал [пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/72059/)

```
#import "Skype4COM.dll" 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) { 
   // Инициализмруем COM соединение 
   CoInitialize(NULL); 

   // Создаем Skype объект 
   SKYPE4COMLib::ISkypePtr pSkype(__uuidof(SKYPE4COMLib::Skype)); 

   // Соединяемся с Skype API 
   pSkype->Attach(6,VARIANT_TRUE); 

   // Получаем версию клиента и выводим ее 
   _bstr_t bstrSkypeVersion = pSkype->GetVersion(); 
   printf("Skype client version %s\n", (char*)bstrSkypeVersion); 

   //Печатаем версию COM "обертки" 
   _bstr_t bstrWrapperVersion = pSkype->GetApiWrapperVersion(); 
   printf("COM wrapper version %s\n", (char*)bstrWrapperVersion); 

   // Удаляем соединения со скайп 
   pSkype = NULL; 
   CoUninitialize(); 

   return 0; 
}
```

При компиляции падает с ошибкой

```
D:\skype_bot\Skype4COM.dll error: stray '\220' in program
```

Компилятор TDM GCC 4.8.1, среда Code::Blocks 13.12.
В каком направлении копать или что я вообще не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня подозрение, что вам придётся воспользоваться VC++. В VC++ `#import` — это прибамбас для COM, в GCC это устаревшая вариация `#include` (отсюда и жалобы компилятора на странные символы).

Различные варианты подключения COM-библиотеки в GCC рассмотрены в вопросе [VC++ #import directive for GCC/G++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050826/vc-import-directive-for-gcc-g). В комментариях там народ жалуется, что не очень-то работает.

Comment: да, gcc говороил об этом, но с #include такая же проблема. там возможно проблема в самом dll конечно, но я в это не верю. а VC++ просто не стоит, не могу проверить, может есть тут добрые люди, которые бы проверили?

Comment: `#import` в нужном вам режиме (читать: как в VC++) в GCC не работает. Вообще никак. Если вам очень повезёт, то после диких танцев с бубном вам получится что-то сделать. Но `#import` вы работать не заставите.

Comment: @Flowneee Обновил ответ. Можете покурить ссылки на указанной странице. Но я бы не очень рассчитывал на успех.

Answer (score 0):

Может, имеет смысл попробовать собрать в каком-нибудь msvc. Впрочем, API у скайпа, вроде, давно уже ликвидировано, поэтому вряд ли будет профит даже если и соберётся.